# How to get API to output one parameter in JSON

Tags: python, todoist

I'm trying to withdraw all the tasks from a specific project within Todoist using [their API](https://developer.todoist.com/rest/v1/#overview) and Python.

My code looks like this:

```py
ListOfProjects = api.get_projects()

ListOfPeople = api.get_tasks(project_id = 1234567899,)

file = open('outputa.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8")

print(ListOfPeople, file = file)

file.close()

input("Press Enter To Exit")
```

This then prints the JSON Encoded information to said file, for example:

```json
[
    Task(
        id: 2995104339,
        project_id: 2203306141,
        section_id: 7025,
        parent_id: 2995104589,
        content: 'Buy Milk',
        description: '',
        comment_count: 10,
        assignee: 2671142,
        assigner: 2671362,
        order: 1,
        priority: 1,
        url: 'https://todoist.com/showTask?id=2995104339'
    ...
)
```

This gives me a massive, unwieldy text document (as there is one of the above for every task in a nearly 300 task project). I just need the string after the `Content` parameter.

Is there a way to specify that just the `Content` parameter should be printed?

Comment: The information shown in your question as the contents of the file is not JSON encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to documentation, `get_tasks` method returns a list of Task object, so if you need to store just `content` property for each of them, you can change your code like this:

```
data = [t.content for t in api.get_tasks(project_id = 1234567899,)]
with open('outputa.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    print(data, file=f)
```

Comment: Perfect! That works great. If i may ask, what does this line do?:  `data = [t.content for t in api.get_tasks(project_id = 1234567899,)]`

Comment: @Oliver: That line is assigning the result of a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to the variable `data`.

Comment: Hi again @martineau, I'm trying to do a similar thing further down in my code where I create a new project, assign it to a variable, and then try and pull the project id from that code to assign that to a variable. However, when I try and use, for example `t.id`, it doesn't see it as a variable to be extracted, the way it did with `t.content`. Here is the code: `newproject = api.add_project(name='Ideas for the Schedule EDIT')

for t in api.get_project(newproject):
    newprojectid = t.id in newproject`

Comment: @Oliver: As far as I can tell, that code is not a list comprehension. I also think you would need to call `api.get_projects()`, not `api.get_project()` if you want to iterate over a series of project objects.